# Extract SQL query from view definition in Spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

Using Spark, I would like to extract the actual SQL statement from a view definition.

My view definition looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW my_schema.my_view (ID , MYVAL ) 
AS select * from my_schema.my_table
```

I would like to extract the part after "AS" .

My crude attempt was this (in Scala):

```
val viewSql = spark.sql("show create table my_schema.my_view").head.getString(0)   
val asKeywordLocation = viewSql.indexOf("AS")   
println(viewSql.substring(asKeywordLocation + 2)
```

But this of course only works if AS is not part of the view name and not part of any column name.
Any Ideas how to solve this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on a dummy case. Can't find any documentation on whether this will ever be truncated for a very long view definition. `data_type` is a string so it allows for large text, but it's worth vetting before running with it.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-ref-syntax-aux-describe-table.html

```
val view_sql = spark.sql(
  "desc extended your_schema.your_view").
  filter("col_name = 'View Text'").
  select("data_type").
  collect()(0)(0)
println(view_sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I created a view with 1600 lines, and it still worked.